# Error pip-uninstalling my own package

Tags: python, pip

I can't seem to be able to uninstall a package I created and installed from a tar.gz.

Any package downloaded from the python index can be uninstalled, but my own does not seem to work.

I've created my own package using:

```
python setup.py sdist
```

installed it using:

```
sudo pip install ./dist/my-package-v1.1.tar.gz
```

The package is installed and works fine.
When I try to uninstall:

```
sudo pip uninstall my-package
```

I get:

```
Can't uninstall 'my-package'. No files were found to uninstall.
```

The package is installed and the name is correct. I made sure by:

```
$ sudo pip freeze | grep my-package
my-package==1.1
```

The only way I am able to uninstall it right now is to manually delete the folder in
`/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` by:

```
sudo rm -Rf /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/my-package
```

Why does pip not work?

BTW: maybe this helps?:

```
whereis python
python: /usr/bin/python3.3m /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python2.7-config /usr/bin/python3.3 /usr/bin/python2.7 /etc/python /etc/python3.3 /etc/python2.7 /usr/lib/python3.3 /usr/lib/python2.7 /usr/bin/X11/python3.3m /usr/bin/X11/python /usr/bin/X11/python2.7-config /usr/bin/X11/python3.3 /usr/bin/X11/python2.7 /usr/local/lib/python3.3 /usr/local/lib/python2.7 /usr/include/python2.7 /usr/share/python /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating setuptools solved the problem for me:
`pip install -U setuptools` (in my case, it leaped from version 5.7 to 12.0.3).